# compare two tables and mark only the same bind of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare

[image]

i have 2 tables with 2 columns and in for every cell in both columns the data is binded together -> can you help me to make compare of 2 tables which contains the same data for some students and to have such output as i have it on a picture? thank you so much

Comment: You can use conditional formatting for this. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: the issue that i can use conditional formatting to compare the same time 2 cells with other 2 cells, it didnt work :(

Comment: Use a rule based on the formula COUNTIFS.